# C#: Method is altering original array that I didn't want it to

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an issue with my program that I am stuck on. Basically the processResults takes my 2D array and returns the sum of each column in the form of a 1D array e.g {15, 13, 19}. calculateWiningResult then **rearranges** this 1D array to find the largest result in the array and returns the **value** of this largest result. In displayWinningResult I want to use the original **unsorted** array to perform some calculations, however it seems to be receiving the **sorted** array from the parameters. Sorry I'm new to programming and am unsure how to get around this.

```
int[,] theResults = {{4, 7, 4},
                     {5, 1, 7},
                     {6, 5, 8}}

int[] results = processResults(theResults);
int winningResult = calculateWiningResult(results);
displayWinningResult(winningResult, results);
```

Comment: You can not ask your teacher to explain? You should try it yourself first

Comment: I'd guess that the `calculateWiningResult` method changes the value of the `results` array. Have you considered refactoring `calculateWiningResult` to **not** change `results`?

Answer (score 2):

C# passes references by value, so when you call `calculateWinningResult(results)` presumably you are sorting `results` which has the effect of, guess what, sorting `results`. It appears that you think `results` is being passed by value which would mean a copy of `results` is passed into `calculateWinningResult` and the original is left unaffected. You might want:

```
int[] resultsCopy = new int[results.Length];
Array.Copy(results, resultsCopy, results.Length);
int winningResult = calculateWiningResult(resultsCopy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Use the copy or Clone.

```
 public void myCoolFunction()
 {
    int[,] theResults = new int [rowNum,colNum]{{4, 7, 4},       
               {5, 1, 7},
               {6, 5, 8}};  
     int[,] copyTheResult = (int[,]) theResult.Clone();

     int[] results = processResults(theResults);
        // Similary you can do for all arrays.
 }
```

Comment: Be careful with Clone though since it only does a shallow copy. In this case the elements are primitives, so it doesn't matter, but if they were Objects you could end up with unexpected behavior.

Comment: @JoelsElf. You are right! Also `Array.copy` can hold a Vector and not a Matrix (2D Array). It puts a 2D array into a single vector.